# Writing VTK file from Python for use in Paraview

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vtk, paraview

I have a Unstructured Grid VTK legacy file which is read using Python and the velocity calculated and stored as a Numpy array. I am looking to firstly export the array to its own VTK file for use in Paraview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `VTK_data` is, as the error said, a `vtkFloatArray`. It does not have a `GetOutput()` method and it cannot be written as an UnstructuredGrid.

You have to add your array to your dataset `data` and then you can write `data` with the writer:

```py
VTK_data.SetName("VELOCITY")
data.GetPointData().AddArray(VTK_data)

writer = vtk.vtkUnstructuredGridWriter()
writer.SetFileName("Output.vtk")
writer.SetInputData(data)
writer.Update()
writer.Write()
```

Comment: what type of object is "data"? How do you create it?

Comment: `data` is a subclass of `vtkDataSet`. Here it should be a `vtkUnstructuredGrid()`. In that case it was created by reading a file with the `vtkUnstructuredGridReader`.